# Postgresql jsonb WHERE Clause

Tags: json, postgresql

I have to tables which each contains a jsonb column.

In Table A I have row where the jsonb contains:

`{"A":"Some1","B":"Some2","C":"Some3","D":Some4"}`

In Table B I have a row with the following value in a jsonb column:

`{"A":"Some1","D":Some4"}`

How do I query Table B with the jsonb value from Table A?

I have been looking into "jsonb Containment" and the @> but the jsonb value from Table A contains more key/values than exist in Table B, and I would like to see all rows in Table B where the key/values match from Table A.

Comment: `@>` will work in this case e..g `from a join b on a.data @> b.data`

Comment: Your are right, it did work, thanks for the help.